# SBT task preceding compilation doesn't get executed in triggered compilation

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26729282/play-sass-not-working) I figured I will learn about sbt tasks and create on of my own. I've reached a stage where I've created a task that runs before compilation and compiles my sass.

```
val sassCompile = TaskKey[ Unit ]( "sassCompile" )

sassCompile := { 
  SassCompiler.compile( baseDirectory.value )
}

watchSources <++= baseDirectory map { path => ((path / "app" / "assets" ) ** "*.scss").get }

compile <<= (compile in Compile) dependsOn sassCompile
```

I do two things:

1. Ensure that every change to scss triggers compilation
2. Before compilation, sass compiler runs

So what works:

1. Triggered compilation works. Every time I change my scala, compilation triggers. (Usual behaviour). Every time I change .scss inside the mentioned path: app/assets/**, compilation triggers. Everything fine.
2. When I manually type compile on the play console, the sass compilation also triggers and I can see the css file change.

What doesn't work:

When compilation is triggered automatically (by virtue of calling ~compile or ~run and then making a change (or even not making a change), sass compilation does not get called. So when I do play ~run, my sass compiler doesn't get invoked.

EDIT: If it helps, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045860/sbt-apply-task-after-compile/17243926#comment42199458_17243926) is a similar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the last line to:

```
compile in Compile <<= (compile in Compile) dependsOn sassCompile
```

Explanation to this you can find [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html) in "When to specify a scope" section.

Comment: Sorry I unmarked this as the answer. Because this now creates the issue that for every request, my sassCompile job runs a large number of times. I can't find the pattern for the number of times, but to given an idea I had the task run at least 20 times after I requested for a webpage.

Comment: @user247077 Could you write more about this new problem. How do you run your application, in which mode? Maybe this problem is similar to [tihs](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/a9xfBiyAI6s/N3qrbrOAAtwJ)